# Intentionally bringing flask down

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

To practice using `supervisor` keeping a flask server alive, I insert a `sys.exit()`:

```
import sys
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    sys.exit()
    return 'Hello, World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Launching in either development through `flask run` or in production through `gunicorn app:app` produces, resp., the errors

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

but neither brings down the server, or else flask restarts on its own. What is happening, and how can I intentionally bring a flask server down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `os._exit()` which does an immediate program termination. `sys.exit()` raises SystemExit exception and will only kill the current thread.